# Using local storage to change CSS background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little trouble with a JavaScript piece of code.

The code is as it follows:`

```
$(switchBackground);
var oFReader = new FileReader(),
    rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
    switchBackground();
};

function switchBackground() {
  var backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('b');
  if (backgroundImage) {
    $('#profile').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');    
  } 
}

function loadImageFile(testEl) {
  if (! testEl.files.length) { return; }
  var oFile = testEl.files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

`

And my problem is the following, as  I don't have almost any knowledge in JavaScript I'm having a hard time figuring out how to clone that code.
I have 2 `<div>`'s - one with `id="profile"` and the other with `id="start-menu"`, I want the users of my web page to be able to change the background image of both `<div>`'s but untill now I have only been able to change the `<div>` with the `id="profile"`. And the way that they change those backgrounds is through an input button, more exactly this one:

```
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
```

I have already tried adding some other characters to some of the functions names, and then just change `id="test2"` or `onchange="loadImageFile2(this)`, but untill now I haven't been successful.
By the way, I should mention that I don't want the backgrounds to be changed with the same button, there are 2 diffrent input buttons, both with the same structure as above (except for the function calling they are almost the same).

What exactly do I need to change at the JS code above in order for it to work with both `div`'s? Please be at your clearest when writing an answer, as my primar language is not english and sometimes I understand certaint phrases a bit harder.

Comment: That's why I'm having a hard time figuring it out, it wasn't written by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the important one:

```
$('#profile').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');
```

See the `#profile` part? That is a [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). That is telling the browser to change the background for the `div` with ID=profile. If you changed that to this:

```
$('#start-menu').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage + ')');
```

Then it would update the other div.

If you want it to update the two divs with the same images just do this:

```
function switchBackground() {
    var backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('b');
    if (backgroundImage) {
        $('#profile').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage +')');
        $('#start-menu').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImage +')');   
    } 
}
```

If you wanted them to be separate images then you'd have to amend the switchBackground function to accept a parameter for which div to switch.

Comment: Yes, I wanted them separate, it would be most helpfull.

Comment: I tried what you said, but it still doesn't work, actually I somehow managed to break it. Is there any way to make a second .js file with the same script just some changed functions name and then call it with the input button in order for it to change the second div's background-image?

Comment: You should post your own answer with the code that made it work so that others that find this answer can learn as well.